# What is the code for creating an animation carousel?

Tags: html, css, animation, carousel

I was wondering if someone could help me with this.

I have a similar carousel like this but for some reason since Edge and Chrome have been updated it has stopped working properly. For example, it should be able to loop back around to the first slide but it slide 4 goes back to slide 3.

I have updated all the software that I am using to see if I could minimise this problem. But again it is still happening since I have updated the software. I thought it could be either of two things.

The code is all good and the browser has messed up certain updates for the code the be recognised.
Or the code is messed up somewhere and I need to figure out why it isn't going back to the start.

```css
@keyframes tonext {
  75% {
    left: 0;
  }
  95% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  98% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  99% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes tostart {
  75% {
    left: 0;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  98% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  99% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes snap {
  96% {
    scroll-snap-align: center;
  }
  97% {
    scroll-snap-align: none;
  }
  99% {
    scroll-snap-align: none;
  }
  100% {
    scroll-snap-align: center;
  }
}

body {
  max-width: 37.5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.25rem;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scrollbar-color: transparent transparent; /* thumb and track color */
  scrollbar-width: 0px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

* {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

ol, li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 75%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px #0003);
  perspective: 100px;
}

.carousel__viewport {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  counter-reset: item;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.carousel__slide {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f99;
  counter-increment: item;
}

.carousel__slide:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #99f;
}

.carousel__slide:before {
  content: counter(item);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-40%,70px);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.carousel__snapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

@media (hover: hover) {
  .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: tonext, snap;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }

  .carousel__slide:last-child .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: tostart, snap;
  }
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .carousel__snapper {
    animation-name: none;
  }
}

.carousel:hover .carousel__snapper,
.carousel:focus-within .carousel__snapper {
  animation-name: none;
}

.carousel__navigation {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.carousel__navigation-list,
.carousel__navigation-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.carousel__navigation-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #333;
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 0.25rem solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
}

.carousel::before,
.carousel::after,
.carousel__prev,
.carousel__next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 37.5%;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.carousel::before,
.carousel__prev {
  left: -1rem;
}

.carousel::after,
.carousel__next {
  right: -1rem;
}

.carousel::before,
.carousel::after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #333;
  background-size: 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.carousel::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpolygon points='0,50 80,100 80,0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.carousel::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpolygon points='100,50 20,100 20,0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS-only Carousel</h1>

<p>This carousel is created with HTML and CSS only.</p>

<section class="carousel" aria-label="Gallery">
  <ol class="carousel__viewport">
    <li id="carousel__slide1"
        tabindex="0"
        class="carousel__slide">
      <div class="carousel__snapper">
        <a href="#carousel__slide4"
           class="carousel__prev">Go to last slide</a>
        <a href="#carousel__slide2"
           class="carousel__next">Go to next slide</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="carousel__slide2"
        tabindex="0"
        class="carousel__slide">
      <div class="carousel__snapper"></div>
      <a href="#carousel__slide1"
         class="carousel__prev">Go to previous slide</a>
      <a href="#carousel__slide3"
         class="carousel__next">Go to next slide</a>
    </li>
    <li id="carousel__slide3"
        tabindex="0"
        class="carousel__slide">
      <div class="carousel__snapper"></div>
      <a href="#carousel__slide2"
         class="carousel__prev">Go to previous slide</a>
      <a href="#carousel__slide4"
         class="carousel__next">Go to next slide</a>
    </li>
    <li id="carousel__slide4"
        tabindex="0"
        class="carousel__slide">
      <div class="carousel__snapper"></div>
      <a href="#carousel__slide3"
         class="carousel__prev">Go to previous slide</a>
      <a href="#carousel__slide1"
         class="carousel__next">Go to first slide</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <aside class="carousel__navigation">
    <ol class="carousel__navigation-list">
      <li class="carousel__navigation-item">
        <a href="#carousel__slide1"
           class="carousel__navigation-button">Go to slide 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__navigation-item">
        <a href="#carousel__slide2"
           class="carousel__navigation-button">Go to slide 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__navigation-item">
        <a href="#carousel__slide3"
           class="carousel__navigation-button">Go to slide 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__navigation-item">
        <a href="#carousel__slide4"
           class="carousel__navigation-button">Go to slide 4</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </aside>
</section>
```